# What's the largest LEGO construction ever?

Tags: records

In terms of the number of bricks used.

Is this house, constructed by James May for the show *Toy Stories*, the biggest?

[image]

Comment: This house was owned and built by James May. Legoland refused to move it and the building was dismantled weeks after construction was over.  The 3.3 million bricks were apparently give to charity. http://techcrunch.com/2009/09/22/james-mays-lego-house-has-been-demolished-try-not-to-cry/

Comment: Isn't this 'off topic'? But not one to become a click-happy close-voter when given the privilege, I guess we could have a few 'fun' questions.

Comment: @muntoo trivia is on topic in most SE sites

Comment: I'm not even sure this is really "trivia" - for Lego fans it is a guide to potential vacation spots.

Comment: MMIX? As in Knuth's MMIX?

Comment: @Pubby8: As in Roman numerals for 2009, the year it was built. No connection. (Though the original MIX was also a numerical pun in Roman numerals.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This house is the biggest lego ever built unless proven otherwise.
I searched a bit and could not find anything using more bricks.

Here are some other project falling short from the 3.3 millions bricks :

- Shopville Le Gru,Grugliasco (Italy), 1.5km long, using 2,901,760 bricks, 13 February 2005
- LEGO Millyard Project at SEE Science Center in Manchester, 3 millions bricks, permanent

Here is a list of LEGO records : http://www.recordholders.org/en/list/lego.html

Answer (score 5):

It depends what you mean by 'construction'. The largest construction project would probably be one of the [LEGOLAND Theme Parks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legoland). The miniland part of the Windsor park alone has 40 million bricks.

James May's Toy Story LEGO home was made with 3.3 million bricks although some of the bricks accounted for the separate models made to furnish the home.